# PWA - protect part of the code from the user

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a PWA that encrypts some data using Open SSL public key when the device is offline and sends it to a server when the device gets back online.

The issue is that if the code of the PWA is inspected the exact structure of the data could be revealed by the user.

Is there any way to hide the public key or a part of the javascript code stored on the user device in PWA?

Answer (score 3):

No code in the client side can be hidden from user, if they choose to inspect, even after installing to home screen, it can be inspected in chrome dev tools.

All you can do is minify and obfuscate your JS files to give hard time for hackers. But not fool proofing it.